# sqlalchemy to load dataframe into sql server table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy to insert records into a sql server table from a pandas dataframe. When running the program, it has issues with the "query=dict(odbc_connec=conn)" statement but I can't figure it out.  Not shown is the code that does the sqlalchemy import as well as the importing of create_engine as well as defining the df.  Below is the code. Is there a syntax error someplace or am I not doing this correctly?

```
conn = (
                      "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
                "Server=servername;"
                "DATABASE=databasename;" +
                "UID=AD-ENT\\" + uid + ";" +
                "PWD=" +pwd + ";" +
                "Trusted_Connection=no;"
               )
        conn_url=sa.create_engine(
                "mssql+pyodbc",
                query=dict(odbc_connect=conn)
        )
        db=sa.create_engine(conn_url, fast_executemany=True)
        #truncate table prior to loading new data
        with db.begin() as conn2:
    
            conn2.exec_driver_sql("DELETE FROM schema.tablename")
        #upload the dataframe
        df.to_sql("schema.tablename", db, schema="schema name", if_exists="replace", index=False)
        connection.close()
```

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should build the URL first and then pass it to `create_engine` like this example:

[pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string)

Comment: I have tried the "from sqlalchemy.engine import URL" but get the message 'cannot import name 'URL' from 'sqlalchemy.engine'.  Python version being used here is 3.7

Comment: What sqlalchemy version though?

Comment: That doc link is for 2.0.  Maybe for 1.3 try `from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL`.